# Unable to install pip in windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am facing issues while installing pip on windows 10

```
C:\Users\AV20027531\Desktop>python get-pip.py

Collecting pip


Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pip/

Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pip/

Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pip/

Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pip/

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pip/

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip
```

*I tried using the command* :  `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
 *same error occurs.* *I don't know what is the problem here.* 
*I am using* `Python 3.6.2`

Comment: pip is a default package management tool. You can find that here `C:\Users\_USER_NAME_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ConnectionResetError

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to connect from office. If that's the case, the possibility is that you can't connect to internet for this upgrade. I faced same issue.

Try coming out of your office network.